# Form of a finite field extension $E/F?$

Tags: field-theory

Suppose $E/F$ is a finite extension. Then $E$ is a finite dimension vector space over $F.$ So let $[E:F] = n$ and with a basis $\{x_1, ..., x_n\}.$ Then can we write $E$ as $E = F(x_1, ..., x_n)?$ Also, can we write $E$ as $E = F[x_1, ..., x_n].$

Comment: yes, and yes${}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have noted, when you say $E$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $F$, you force $F(x_1, \dots, x_n) = F[x_1, \dots, x_n]$.  But the two notations really do mean different things.

First, "$F[x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n]$" is the collection of expressions using addition, subtraction, and multiplication applied to elements of $F \cup \{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$.  (These are *ring* operations and the square brackets indicate a ring extension.)  The set of such expressions is partitioned into equivalence classes containing expressions with the same value, i.e., equal under the properties in the definition of a ring.  (For instance, "$1+x_1$" and "$x_1 + 1$" are in the same class.)  It is not automatically the case that, for instance, $x_1^{-1}$ can be expressed using these ring expressions.

Then "$F(x_1, \dots, x_n)$" is the collection of rational expressions, $\frac{p}{q}$ with $p,q \in F[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ but requiring that $q$ not be in the equivalence class containing $0$.  (Again, partition into classes by equality under field properties.)  It is automatically the case that $x_1^{-1} = \frac{1}{x_1}$ is such a rational expression.  This is a field extension, since it is, first, a ring extension, and also guaranteed to contain the multiplicative inverses of all of its elements.

It can be difficult to find an example of a field extension where the analogous ring extension does not contain all the required inverses.  For instance, in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$, we find $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \in \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$.  The same thing happens with any algebraic extension.

But what about a transcendental extension?  Is there any polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ that is in the $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ equivalence class containing $\frac{1}{x}$?  No; there is no such polynomial.  (What would its degree be?)

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that $E$ is an $F$-vector space with basis $\{x_1,\ldots, x_n\}$, every $x\in E$ can be expressed as $\sum_{i=1}^na_ix_i$ for $a_i\in F$. So this already demonstrates that $E=F[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$ (and so trivially as $F(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$.)